# SUMIFS to sum data between custom date range

Tags: excel, validation, date, excel-formula

I am building a dashboard to summarize purchase data. I have a worksheet for purchase data, there is a reference tables worksheet with the start and end dates for fiscal months, with the associated fiscal year, and fiscal month (summarized below), and the dashboard worksheet.

Table: `oetFiscalMonths`

```
Start Date | End Date | Month    | Year  
10/1/17    | 10/30/17 | October  | 2018  
10/31/17   | 11/1/17  | November | 2018
```

On the dashboard there is a table of data formatted as below

```
         | Beginning Budget | Total Purchases | Remaining Budget |  
October  | $XXXXXXXXX.00    | $XXXXXX.00      | $XXXXXXXXXX.00   |  
November | $XXXXXXXXX.00    | $XXXXXX.00      | $XXXXXXXXXX.00   |  
December | $XXXXXXXXX.00    | $XXXXXX.00      | $XXXXXXXXXX.00   |  
January  | $XXXXXXXXX.00    | $XXXXXX.00      | $XXXXXXXXXX.00   |
```

The formula I am looking to enter would go in the Total purchases, and would sum all purchases made in the fiscal month on the right, based on the table for fiscal months, while meeting several other criteria, which I have been able to complete with the `SUMIFS` formula. I am just not sure how to handle the date range portion as they do not follow the calendar months even remotely mostly, and the table for the dates is formatted the way it is as several other portions utilize its current format.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `sheet1` is your dashboard, `sheet2` contains your `oetFiscalMonths` table and `sheet3` contains the purchases and their corresponding dates of purchase you want to `SUM`, you can make use of `SUMIFS` combined with `INDEX + MATCH` to suite your current file structure:

```
=SUMIFS(sheet3!C:C,sheet3!B:B,">="&INDEX(sheet2!A:A,MATCH(sheet1!A2,sheet2!C:C,0)),sheet3!B:B,"<="&INDEX(sheet2!B:B,MATCH(sheet1!A2,sheet2!C:C,0)))
```

Legends are as follows:

`sheet3!C:C` contains the purchase values you want to `SUM`

`sheet3!B:B` contains the date of purchases

`sheet2!A:A` contains the start dates of your months

`sheet2!B:B` contains the end dates of your months

`sheet2!C:C` contains your months

`sheet1!A2` contains the first month you want to get the `SUM` of purchases of.

Comment: this seems to be working, but because months are in the    oetFoscalMonths     table multiple times, it seems to only be finding the very top result, which results in the sum equaling 0, as all purchases are out of the time frame. There is a total of 4 fiscal years, ranging from 10/1/17 through 9/28/2021.

Comment: Using this answer I was able to figure it out. I needed to change the months in the table to dates of October 1, 2017, etc. for all of them, then needed to use     DATEVALUE()     on the month in the sums table.

Answer (score 1):

You can try also by sumproduct formula, its benefit without open worksheet formula calculating.

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(B:B>=H3)*(B:B<=I3),(C:C))`

C:C = Sum range

B:B = Date search range

H3 = Value of start date

I3 = Value of end date

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SUMIFS like I've shown below.  Excuse the random row and cell usage.  I will try to explain below.

`=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,">="&G1,A:A,"<="&H1)`

C:C = Sum range 
A:A = Date search range 
G1 = Value of start date 
H1 = Value of end date

**EDIT:**
I would suggest moving the months column to the front and then the dates after like shown below.  That way you can use a vlookup to find the date and then incorporate a vlookup into the sumifs.

```
  Month  | Start Date | End Date | Year  
October  | 10/1/17    | 10/30/17 | 2018  
November | 10/31/17   | 11/1/17  | 2018
```

`=SUMIFS(G:G,F:F,">="&VLOOKUP(J6,M:O,2,0),F:F,"<="&VLOOKUP(J6,M:O,3,0))`

M:O is your fiscal year table
J6 is where you would type the month you are searching for
Column 2 in the first VLOOKUP will give you start date
Column 3 in the second VLOOKUP will give you end date

Let me know if you have any questions, it may be kind of confusing since I am using random rows and columns.

Comment: My problem is I am not sure how to pull the start date and end date from the table named oetFiscalMonths based on the month in the left column of the sums table. oetFiscalMonths has about 4 fiscal years worth of start and end dates, otherwise the above formula would work.